# Given Window Handle, listen for on Handle Rect Change event

Tags: c#, winapi, window-handles, window-messages

I have a handle (HWND) to a window and I want to listen for bounding rectangle changes. I could check the [`GetWindowRect(HWND hWnd, LPRECT lpRect);`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633519%28VS.85%29.aspx) every n milliseconds, but that seems really wasteful.

*Is there a Windows message that I can listen for?*

The window handle is not to a window I own.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this if you use [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28VS.85%29.aspx) to install a hook function, and then listen for [WM_SIZE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms632646%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) messages.